# Awesomium doesn't process javascript on page

Tags: javascript, awesomium

I'm experimenting with awesomium now.
Things I've done:
1) created html page with only one script:

```
<script>alert('alert')</script>
```

2) opened that page in awesomium and there was no pop-up windows with text "alert"

Please, tell me how to make awesomium execute javascript on the page.

Comment: You need to give more detail and code. How are you using Awesomium? What language? What version?

Comment: I think it is because the alert should make another dialog window - and that is not a part of the web-page -  I think you need to handle that yourself using OnJavascriptDialog event handler or something....

Answer (score 0):

Update to 1.7.2. JS handling is much better.